# Getting to 100 percent code coverage on my trailhead module "Write Negative Tests Unit"

Tags: unit-test, code-coverage, trailhead

I seem to be stuck on this trailhead module or write negative tests unit, while I have 93 percent code coverage, I can't seem to get the code coverage to hit 100 percent at the "returnValue" piece doesn't seem to hit.

My code is as follows.

Calculator Class

```
public class Calculator {
 public class CalculatorException extends Exception{}

  public static Integer addition(Integer a, Integer b){
   return a + b;
    }

   public static Integer subtraction(Integer a, Integer b){
    return a - b;
    }

 public static Integer multiply(Integer a, Integer b){
  if(b==0 || a==0){
  throw new CalculatorException('It doesn\'t make sense to multiply by 
   zero');
  }
  return a * b;
  }

 public static Decimal divide(Integer numerator, Integer denominator){
  if(denominator == 0){
  throw new CalculatorException('you still can\'t divide by zero');
   }
 Decimal returnValue = numerator / denominator;
  if(returnValue < 0){
    throw new CalculatorException('Division returned a negative value.' + 
 returnValue);
 }
   return returnValue;
  }


 }
```

And the test class

```
  @isTest
   public class Calculator_Tests {

@isTest
 public static void addition() {
    Calculator.addition(1, 0);
   }
@isTest
  public static void subtraction() {
    Calculator.subtraction(1, 0);
   }

@isTest
 public static void divide_throws_exception_for_division_by_zero() {
 Boolean caught = false;
 try {
    Calculator.divide(1, 0);
  } catch (Calculator.CalculatorException e) {
    System.assertEquals('you still can\'t divide by zero', e.getMessage(), 
  'caught the right exception');
    caught = true;
   }
   System.assert(caught, 'threw expected exception');
   }

  @isTest
 public static void divide_throws_exception_for_division_by_two() {
 Boolean caught = true;
 try {
    Calculator.divide(1, 2);
 } catch (Calculator.CalculatorException e) {
    System.assertEquals('you still can\'t divide by zero', e.getMessage(), 
  'caught the right exception');
    caught = true;
   }
   System.assert(caught, 'threw expected exception');
 }


@isTest
public static void multiply_by_one() {
  Boolean caught = false;
  try {
    Calculator.multiply(1, 0);
    } catch (Calculator.CalculatorException e) {
    System.assertEquals('It doesn\'t make sense to multiply by zero', 
    e.getMessage(), 'caught the right exception');
     caught = true;
    }
    System.assert(caught, 'threw expected exception');
  }

@isTest
 public static void multiply_by_two() {
  Boolean caught = true;
  try {
     Calculator.multiply(1, 2);
   } catch (Calculator.CalculatorException e) {
    System.assertEquals('It doesn\'t make sense to multiply by zero', 
  e.getMessage(), 'caught the right exception');
    caught = true;
   }
   System.assert(caught, 'threw expected exception');
}   
}
```

Comment: A little bit of effort to indent your code more consistently would make a large improvement in its readability.

Answer (score 3):

To test this code path,

```
if (returnValue < 0) {
   throw new CalculatorException('Division returned a negative value.' + returnValue);
}
```

You're going to have to contrive input such that the `if` condition evaluates to `true`. What divided by what yields a negative value?

You already have a pattern in place for testing code paths that throw exceptions. You'd simply need to write a version of `divide_throws_exception_for_division_by_zero()` that calls this method with the input values that make `returnValue < 0`, and then makes assertions that check for the corresponding `CalculatorException` and message.

#### Additional Note

`divide_throws_exception_for_division_by_two()` and `multiply_by_two()` are not really testing anything. Both of them assert that `true == true`, trying to catch an exception in a code path that will not throw one, and fail to validate the results of the *successful* call that they make to `divide()` or `multiply()`.

These tests do not need exception handlers because they are testing code that should not throw an exception. You should write assertions based on the *expected behavior of this code*, not tautologies that are guaranteed to pass.

Answer (score 0):

I was running into the same issue. Write a positive test...

Integer two = 2;
Integer four = 4;

System.AssertEquals(2,Calculator.divide(four,two));